# Issue with Currency Field value ending in 0 in an email template

Tags: email, visual-workflow, currency, merge-field

I have a custom field with Data Type = Currency , Length =  16, Decimal Places =    2

In a flow, I have 'Send Email' Action. The body of the email uses the custom currency merge field

When the email is triggered, if the custom currency field value ends with a decimal number 0 then the 0 is omitted. e.g. If the Custom field Currency Amount = 40.24 , the email received correctly displays 40.24
However if the Custom field Currency Amount = 2.70 , the email received displays 2.7

So, If the amount ends with a 0, the email does not display the 0.

I couldn't figure out why ?  Can someone shed some light ?

Edit:
[image]

Image to show EmailBody

[image]

Comment: what kind of email template: text, html, VF, lightning?

Comment: @cropredy simpleEmail in the flow Action. Added screenshot in the question.

Comment: try using an email alert/template instead

Comment: I can't use Email Alert because the email is sent to a collection of recipients. If i use email alert,  I can only select specific type  of Recipients

Comment: use [edit] and show the EmailBody variable - at leats the portion with the custom currency field

Comment: @cropredy added image to show the EmailBody variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cropredy
I was able to resolve the Currency to Text formatting issue based on this [article](https://www.sdocs.com/knowledge-base/sdocs/formatting-data/formatting-currencies/)

Comment: presumably using the formula example at the bottom of that article?